# atof returns could not convert string to float: '2, 5'

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the *atof* method, however, the block below fails with the error in topic title:

```
 import locale
 s='2,5'
 x=locale.atof(s)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try `2.5` instead - what you have is common in Europe but not in the U.S.

Comment: What are your locale settings (ie. where in the world are you)?  It probably wants `2.5` (with a period).  The `atof` method uses the [`locale.LC_NUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.LC_NUMERIC) option.

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat It's actually not all *that* obvious in this case - `2,5` is perfectly valid in parts of Europe (just not in the U.S.). (In fact, the only reason I happen to know that is the fact that I work for a German company).

Comment: Come to think of it, +1 from me because it's *not* obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually have to SET the locale to a place where `,` is the numeric separator, not just import the module. That category is [LC_NUMERIC](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.LC_NUMERIC):

```
import locale
s='2,5'
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')  # 'de_DE' is just an example
x=locale.atof(s)
```

Or if you OS environment is set to a locale where `,` is the numeric separator you can usually do as [recommended in the locale documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) of:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

> This sets the locale for all categories to the user’s default setting
> (typically specified in the LANG environment variable).

Comment: You may prefer `setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')`, since this will use the user’s environment to choose the locale, rather than hard-coding `de_DE`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Just an example, since I don't know what his OS local settings are.... I added that explanation. THANKS!

Comment: Works. Needed to add utf8 though. `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.utf8')`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't [setting the locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) - so I don't know what it might be defaulting to; presumably the system default.

Try this :

```
 import locale
 locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
 s='2,5'
 x=locale.atof(s)
```

This will set the locale for all categories to your users default.

Does that work ?

Comment: If you don’t set the locale, you get the “C” locale.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - what is the 'C' locale - I have never gone anywhere close to localisation

Comment: The C locale uses the English language but simplifies the rules. For example, `strcoll()` is just `strcmp()` in the C locale (but it might behave differently in the “en” locale). See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Thank you. I really ought to think about how to do proper localisation for some of my libraries.